# How to download a website including all files with links starting with a certain path

Tags: wget, httrack

I'd like to build a static website based on the styling of a Wordpress template, [Inovado](http://inovado.hellominti.com/). I downloaded the website using HTTrack (in Linux) with the following command:

`httrack http://inovado.hellominti.com`

The resulting `index.html` contains several stylesheets such as the following:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='basic-css'  href='http://inovado.hellominti.com/wp-content/themes/inovado/framework/css/basic.css?ver=1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

These links are 'absolute' links to `http://inovado.hellominti.com`. However, I'd like to download those files to a local directory, and adjust the `index.html` file accordingly.

I've seen that `httrack` has options such as `--get_files` which seem like they might enable this, but I wasn't able to figure out how from the documentation. Any ideas? (I'd also be interested in implementing this with `wget` if that's possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the recursive option of HTTrack does this: `httrack -r http://inovado.hellominti.com`.

(Incidentally, however, I found a simpler bootstrap template at http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp).